# How can I override a class definition in python?

Tags: python

I have a nested class structure where when I instantiate the top level class it instantiates a bunch of objects of other classes as attributes, and those instantiate a few other classes as their own attributes.

As I develop my code I want to override a class definition in a new module (this would be a good way for me to avoid breaking existing functionality in other scripts while adding new functionality).

As a toy example, there is a module where I define two classes where one has a list of the other, Deck and Card. When I instantiate a Deck object it instantiates a list of Card objects.

**module_1.py**

```
class Card(object):
    def __init__(self, suit, number):
        self.suit = suit
        self.number = number

class Deck(object):
    def __init__(self):
        suit_list = ['heart', 'diamond', 'club', 'spade']
        self.cards = []
        for suit in suit_list:
            for number in range(14):
                self.cards.append(Card(suit, number))
```

I have another type of Card and I want to make a Deck of those, so I import Deck into a new module and define a new Card class in the new module, but when I instantiate Deck, it has cards from module_1.py

**module_2.py**

```
from module_1 import Deck

class Card(object):
    def __init__(self, suit, number):
        self.suit = suit
        self.number = number
        self.index = [suit, number]

if __name__ == '__main__':
    new_deck = Deck()
    print new_deck.cards[0]
```

Output:

```
>python module_2.py
<module_1.Card object at 0x000001>
```

Is there some way that I can use my Deck class from module_1.py but have it use my new Card class?

Passing the class definition is cumbersome because the actual case is deeply nested and I may want to also develop other classes contained within the top level object.

Also, I expected this to be consistent with object oriented paradigms. Is it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Patrick's answer is the recommended way. However, answering to your specific question, it is actually possible.

```
import module_1

class Card(object):
    def __init__(self, suit, number):
        self.suit = suit
        self.number = number
        self.index = [suit, number]

if __name__ == '__main__':
    # Keep reference to the original Card class.
    original_card = module_1.Card
    # Replace with my custom Card class.
    module_1.Card = Card  
    new_deck = module_1.Deck()
    print new_deck.cards[0]
    # Restore.
    module_1.Card = original_card
```

Comment: How does this answer the "specific question" more so than Patrick's answer or my deleted answer? I suppose if you assume OP doesn't want to modify the code for `Deck`.

Comment: @Cyphase Well, the question says "How can I override a class definition in python?". Here's how you can do it.

Comment: It's true that this will override the Card class definition instead of modifying the Deck class, but you should mention that it renders the original Card definition unreachable...

Comment: @PatrickMaupin Yes, that's why I keep a reference to the original `Card` class before replacing it.

Comment: Ah, you mean the question title. Fair enough.

Comment: For this use-case, this monkey-patching works fine.  Just hope it's not on a multithreaded card game server where different users pick different kinds of cards :-)

Comment: This is perfect! Thank you!

Comment: @Patrick Maupin Thank you for teaching me the term monkey-patching!

Comment: I expected that this type of overriding a class definition would be consistent with OOP paradigms. It seems very similar to overriding a method when inheriting a class. Why is this not a common or preferred technique?

Comment: @S.Stromberg As mentioned, this would be a problem for a multi-threaded program, you will always need to use `import module_1` instead of `from module_1 import` and Patrick's example is more readable.

Comment: So to make sure I understand, in a multi-threaded program this wouldn't work because I can only use one Card class. 

Separately, I can't import using from because I need the module name to find the old Class definition and replace it.

And it's readability is difficult because I import then I define the class, then I replace the one from the import, so it takes some detective work.

Answer (score 5):

Make the Card class an optional parameter to the Deck instance initializer that defaults to your initial Card class, and override it by passing a second parameter of your second Card class when you initialize a deck of your new cards.

**EDIT** Made names more Pythonic and made index a tuple as suggested by cyphase .

```
class Card(object):
    def __init__(self, suit, number):
        self.suit = suit
        self.number = number

class Deck(object):
    def __init__(self, card_type=Card):
        suit_list = ['heart', 'diamond', 'club', 'spade']
        self.cards = []
        for suit in suit_list:
            for number in range(14):
                self.cards.append(card_type(suit, number))
```

Your second module will pass its Card class into the Deck:

```
from module_1 import Deck

class FancyCard(object):
    def __init__(self, suit, number):
        self.suit = suit
        self.number = number
        self.index = suit, number

if __name__ == '__main__':
    new_deck = Deck(FancyCard)
    print new_deck.cards[0]
```

Comment: Also, `self.index` should be a `tuple` ;).

Comment: Thank you. This is a good solution for the toy problem. Unfortunately I have a much more complicated data structure so namespace gymnastics is preferable. For this implementation I need to send in the reference to the class definition at each level if I'm replacing a class at the bottom.

Answer (score 0):

To make collections of interrelated classes customizable, I would not hard-code a class choice in the code of the class. Instead, I would make use of class-variables to allow for the selection of an alternate class.

```
# module 1

class Card(object):
    def __init__(self, suit, number):
        self.suit = suit
        self.number = number

class Deck(object):

    CardCls = None

    def __init__(self, card_type=Card):
        suit_list = ['heart', 'diamond', 'club', 'spade']
        self.cards = []
        CardCls = self.CardCls or Card
        for suit in suit_list:
            for number in range(14):
                self.cards.append(CardCls(suit, number))
```

and

```
# module 2
from module_1 import Deck

class NewCard(object):
    def __init__(self, suit, number):
        self.suit = suit
        self.number = number
        self.index = [suit, number]

class NewDeck(Deck):
    CardCls = NewCard
```

Alternatively, you could initially code `Deck` like this instead:

```
class Deck(object):

    CardCls = Card

    def __init__(self, card_type=Card):
        suit_list = ['heart', 'diamond', 'club', 'spade']
        self.cards = []
        for suit in suit_list:
            for number in range(14):
                self.cards.append(self.CardCls(suit, number))
```

*But* this requires `Card` to be defined before `Deck` in the originating module, or to be wired into the class later like:

```
Deck.CardCls = Card
```

So, I find it more flexible to use a pattern like:

```
CardCls = self.CardCls or Card
```

This way, the order of class definitions in a module doesn't matter. If the instance of the `Deck` subclass in question has a variable `self.CardCls` set (a "truthy" value -- which it will if you set it as a class-level variable in a subclass) it will use that. If it doesn't, it will use the `Card` class defined in the same module with the `Deck` base class.

Comment: Thanks Matt. The reason I want to override the class definition instead of pass a class is that the list I want to modify is deep in a class structure, so I would need to pass a bunch of class definitions as I develop. I'll edit my question to add that info.

Comment: @S.Stromberg If I understand what you're asking, you cannot do it. Classes and functions defined in a module use that module as their namespace. Importing a class into another module does not mean that the imported class can see anything in the second module's namespace.  If you want to override a lookup, you have to construct your class with a hook such that you can tell it to use an alternative object (class, function, whatever) and then use the hook. The only alternative to that is to mutate the original namespace, as cdonts suggests.